# How to store 2D array elements in an empty 3D array using nested for loops in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to store the elements/values of a 2D array into a 3D array but I'm a bit confused on how to do it using nested for loops..

Here's my source code:

```java
//3D array that only stores up to 10 unique elements only
String[][][] ProductAllData2 = new String[10][10][8];
// 2D array (has a function (which takes a parameter)
// that returns values then stores it in this 2D array)
String[][] receivedPInputsWithParameter =
        getPInputsWithParameter(ProductAllData1);

int Product3DINDEX = 0;    // index of 3D array
int Product3DVARIETY = 0;  // index of 3D array
int Product3DCOLUMN = 0;   // index of 3D array (not sure if this one is usable)
```

My first technique of using nested for loops:

(But it returns an error "incomaptible types: String cannot be converted to String[]" in this line:  ProductAllData2[Product3DINDEX][Product3DVARIETY] = receivedPInputsWithParameter[m][n]; )

```java
// stores 2D array in 3D array
for (int m = 0; m < receivedPInputsWithParameter.length; m++) {
  for (int n = 0; n < receivedPInputsWithParameter[n].length; n++) {
    ProductAllData2[Product3DINDEX][Product3DVARIETY] =
            receivedPInputsWithParameter[m][n];
    Product3DINDEX++;
    roduct3DVARIETY++;
  }
}
```

My second technique of using nested for loops:

(But I get an index out of bounds exception of 8 in the line:       ProductAllData2[Product3DINDEX][Product3DVARIETY][Product3DCOLUMN] = receivedPInputsWithParameter[j][k];

```java
//Inserts the 2D array(receivedPInputsWithParameter) in 3D array(ProductAllData2)
for (int i = 0; i < ProductAllData2.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < ProductAllData2[i].length; j++) {
    ProductAllData2[i][j] = new String[receivedPInputsWithParameter[j].length];
    for (int k = 0; k < ProductAllData2[i][j].length; k++) {
      ProductAllData2[Product3DINDEX][Product3DVARIETY][Product3DCOLUMN] =
              receivedPInputsWithParameter[j][k];
      Product3DINDEX++;
      Product3DVARIETY++;
      Product3DCOLUMN++;
    }
  }
}
```

Do I need to fix or change something in my nested for loops??
Your responses and guides would indeed help me a lot!!

Comment: If you still need help with this one, please clarify how exactly you want to copy the 2D array into a 3D one. would you like the 2D data to all exist within the first index of the 3D array?

Comment: Yes I wanted the 2D data to exist in the first index of the 3D array but I resolved it last two weeks ago, so I think I'm good here Moshe^_^

Comment: all right, awesome